# An application to "take over" Windows

Tags: .net, wpf

As the title states, I am in need of an application to act almost like an operating system.

I want the user to see nothing but my window, so it will have to be fullscreen. That's no problem, but what is is how the user would easily be able to alt+tab, windows key+tab or just shut the application down completely.

That's not what I'm after, since I want an application to be the only thing a user can use,
similar to how schools have their "in house applications" and how some ATM works.

How would one go about and do such a thing?

I currently have no code to give you, since I don't know the right way to tackle this yet.

Comment: WinXP had "kiosk mode" which was designed specifically for this - now that you know the term you might be able to see if it's available on other editions of the OS.

Comment: @Alex, change registry so on startup instead of starting explorer your application is starterd which fills whole screen

Comment: What OS are you on? Windows 8.1 has a kiosk mode, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought while reading your question was, *It's almost as if he wants the equivalent of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) "/dev/null"ing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>*.

Windows kiosk mode or other solutions probably make more sense, but I figured I would offer and explore this thought a bit...as food for thought if nothing else.

[Disabling <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/81941-disable-alttab-in-wow-stopped-working/) in a specific app or generally is definitely doable with an AHK script.

To avoid your app depending on AHK being installed, convert its AHK script to an executable using [`ahk2exe.exe`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe).

To manipulate other keyboard or mouse input, simply enhance your app's AHK script (and convert it to an enhanced executable).

Comment: I sort of went with this solution among with one other, changing or adding some values temporarily in the registry that disables taskmanager and some functions in the security screen (Windows 7 alt+ctrl+del)

Instead of autohotkey I used a keyboardhook to detect commands linked to closing or removing the focus from my application, such as  windows key, alt+f4, alt+tab and so on.

I will mark your answer as solution when I am ready to post the full solution I came up with, for any future visitors.